# Read highest foldername with batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm desperately trying to read the highest foldername to create 10 new folders with consecutive names.
The folders have numbers as names e.g. 1234,1235,1236.

```
SET datei=0
FOR /D %%a IN (*) DO (
    ECHO %datei%
    IF %%a GTR %datei% SET datei=%%a
)
ECHO %datei%
```

The output is

```
0
0
0
1234
```

not what i expected, can anyone help please?
Is there an issue with number vs string?

regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your batch code does not work because `%datei%` in **IF** command line is expanded (replaced) by `0` already on preprocessing entire command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` before the **FOR** command is executed at all. Open a command prompt window and run `set /?` explaining *delayed environment variable expansion* on an **IF** and a **FOR** example and read for example this article about [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). This behavior of `cmd.exe` executing the batch file can be also seen on removing `@echo off` from top of batch file and run it from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on batch file (= debugging a batch file).

This batch code should work which avoids the requirement to use delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir * /AD /B /O-N 2^>nul') do set "FolderName=%%I" & goto FoundFolder
set "FolderName=0001"

:FoundFolder
rem Print the name of the folder with highest number.
set FolderName
```

The command **DIR** outputs

- just folder names because of `/AD` (attribute directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*` in current directory
- in bare format because of `/B` which means just folder name without path
- sorted alphabetically by name in reverse order because of `/O-N`.

So the first line output by **DIR** is the folder name with highest number as long as all folder names have same number of digits which is the case according to example posted in question. This folder name is assigned to an environment variable and loop is exited before processing the other folder names output by **DIR** with a jump to label `FoundFolder`.

It would be also possible to use this code working for folder names with different number of digits using delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderName=0"

for /D %%I in (*) do (
    echo !FolderName!
    if %%I GTR !FolderName! set "FolderName=%%I"
)

echo !FolderName!
rem Other commands in batch file.
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.